# Copying Multiple files with specific extension

Tags: file, powershell, batch-file, copying

So I have this little problem...

(Windows 10 Education N x64)

I am a GoldSrc engine developer and i am trying to achieve the
 following thing with Batch script or PowerShell, to do that automated
 task by itself instead of me manually picking every damn folder,
 eventually to spare time. :)

I am having directory structure as following:

Main(root) folder names "GoldSrc" is located at "Desktop"

So it goes like this:

Absolute Path:

Image from TREE VIEW:

[image: Image from TREE VIEW]

```
[Main folder]
C:\Users\Andrej Poženel\Desktop\GoldSrc

[Source directory to copy from with recursive subdirectories]
C:\Users\Andrej Poženel\Desktop\GoldSrc\prefabs

[Directory to copy to]
C:\Users\Andrej Poženel\Desktop\GoldSrc\Maps
```

I want to lookup into subfolder named "prefabs" and search all
 subfolders in that directory for files that have file extension .map 
 AND  .rmf, so both filters together and copy them from its source
 location [../GoldSrc/prefabs/like_100_folders_here] to "GoldSrc"
 subdirectory named "Maps", everything shown on picture)

So i want the things look like this after this process:

`C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\GoldSrc\Maps`: blabla.map bleble.rmf
 bleble.rmf cacac.rmf adasdad.map ...

and not each file in its own directory like it is in source dir...

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no way that a file have ".map AND .rmf extension", just one of them. Perhaps you want files that have ".map OR .rmf extension"...

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code request site, it is a place where you seek help with issues relating to your own code. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46141258/edit) with your problem code, ensuring that your chosen tags are also relevant.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to post my code...

Comment: @echo off
color 0a

rem remark1

cd
echo Start copying MAP and RMF files by pressing any key on keyboard!

pause

xcopy ../prefabs*.rmf ../prefabs/maps
xcopy ../prefabs*.map ../prefabs/maps

pause

Comment: @Aacini  I meant not the thing you are implying: somefilename.map.rmf   BUT somefilename22.map AND  somefilename56.rmf

Comment: Thanks for help and feedbacks

Comment: This is a programming site for programmers. The operations used in a programming language (like a Batch file) are exact and precise. The way to solve your problem is reviewing a series of files and take just the ones that have ".map [OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) .rmf extension", _NOT_ the ones that have ".map [AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) .rmf extension". Another way to say the same thing is "the files with .map extension AND the files with .rmf extension".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pushd "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\GoldSrc"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d .\prefabs\*.map .\prefabs\*.rmf')  do ECHO copy "%%a" ".\maps\"
popd
```

Should execute this.

First move to the required subdirectory, then perform a directory scan including subdirectories in basic form and excluding directorynames. For each returned line matching either of the filespecs, assign the name found to `%%a`, then copy that file to the required subdirectory.

then return to the original directory.

The commands generated will simply be `echo`ed to the console. To actually execute the command (after checking), remove the `ECHO` keyword.

Note that this is a batch file, and not intended to be executed directly from the prompt.

Comment: Here is the code i got from my Batch knowlegde... :( ,  Thanks for answer

Comment: @echo off
color 0a

rem remark1

cd
echo Start copying MAP and RMF files by pressing any key on keyboard!

pause

xcopy ../prefabs*.rmf ../prefabs/maps
xcopy ../prefabs*.map ../prefabs/maps

pause

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the Powershell way, you can use the below code

```
gci "C:\Users\Andrej Poženel\Desktop\GoldSrc\prefabs" -filter *.map | %{
copy-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\Andrej Poženel\Desktop\GoldSrc\Maps"}

gci "C:\Users\Andrej Poženel\Desktop\GoldSrc\prefabs" -filter *.rmf | %{
copy-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\Andrej Poženel\Desktop\GoldSrc\Maps"}
```

or

```
gci "C:\Users\Andrej Poženel\Desktop\GoldSrc\prefabs" -recurse | ?{
!$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.Extension -match "map|rmf" } | %{
copy-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\Andrej Poženel\Desktop\GoldSrc\Maps"}
```

Comment: Thank You for the PS code, i was tried to write that in any command line processor app that is bundled with Windows, either PS or batch

Comment: Rather than doing it as two separate `gci` command, you could do a `where-object` test.  `gci "pathname" -recurse | ?{ !$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.Extension -match "map|rmf" } | %{ copy stuff }`  (The question mark is shorthand for `where-object`, just as the percent sign is shorthand for `foreach-object`.)

Comment: Ahh yeah that is another way... I couldn't think of a way to pair the two in one statement